# DLL Import corrupting memory

Tags: c#

I am receiving this error while using a dllimport `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt`

```
private const string dir2 = @"C:\NBioBSP.dll";

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(dir2, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern uint NBioAPI_FreeFIRHandle(IntPtr hHandle, IntPtr hFIR);
```

I call it like this

```
uint resultado = NBioAPI_FreeFIRHandle(handle, handle);
```

Anyone know what the issue can be

Comment: And where did you get `handle` from?

Answer (score 5):

Two problems.

First, the calling convention is wrong. Per [the header file that defines the function](https://github.com/fabiocerqueira/nbio/blob/master/include/NBioAPI.h) (as well as [the supporting file that defines `NBioAPI`](https://github.com/fabiocerqueira/nbio/blob/master/include/NBioAPI_Basic.h) as `__stdcall` on the Win32 platform), you should be using [`CallingConvention.StdCall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx).

Second, in [the header that defines the types](https://github.com/fabiocerqueira/nbio/blob/master/include/NBioAPI_Type.h) used by the API, `NBioAPI_HANDLE` and `NBioAPI_FIR_HANDLE` are `typedef`'d to `UINT`, which is always 32 bits (four bytes) long. You're using [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx), which has a platform-dependent size (it will be 64 bits in a 64-bit process.) Change the function parameters to `uint`.